# Python print statement not showing up in If in range statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, numbers, range

I have looked online on how to write a if in range statement in python and I am confused why my print statement is not showing up.

```
print("Hello User What Is The Wind Chill Today?")
windChill = int(input())

if windChill <= -25:
    print("No School!!!")

if windChill >= 0:
    print("Theres School ):")

if int(windChill) in range(-1, -24):
    print("Maybe school")
```

The expected result is that if I put in the input -20 it will say "Maybe school" but right now it is not showing the print statement when I put in a number through -1 to -24.

Comment: `range` naturally increments in `+1` unless specified otherwise. In this case, that's an empty range because there are no number of `1`s you can add to `-1` to get to `-24`. You need it to decrement: `if int(windChill) in range(-1, -24, -1):`

Comment: you need to use `range(-24, -1)` `-24` is lower than `-1`. Or see @roganjosh's comment

Comment: If-elif-else would be the more pythonic syntax to use here. There can be unintended consequences if you are using 3 if statements in that is the syntax you use for conditional checking using python

Answer (score 3):

Python's [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function increments in values of 1. The first argument in `range` is `start` the second is `stop` and a 3'rd *(optional)* argument is `step` which is what it increments by. You have 2 options here.

**Either start from the lower number and stop at the higher**:

```
if int(windChill) in range(-24, -1):
```

**Or keep what you have but tell `range` to increment by -1**:

```
if int(windChill) in range(-1, -24, -1):
```

Both the above will accomplish the same result for you, although just fyi they both will result in reversed list's of eachother if you run `list()` on them

```
print(list(range(-24, -1)))
#[-24, -23, -22, -21, -20, -19, -18, -17, -16, -15, -14, -13, -12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2]

print(list(range(-1, -24, -1)))
#[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19, -20, -21, -22, -23]
```

**Edit**

If you dig deeper, the ranges are determined using the following formulas:

> For a positive step, the contents of a range `r` are determined by the
>   formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by
>   the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and
>   `r[i] > stop`.
>
> [Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range)

So in essence, `range` is actually excluding the stop value in my examples *(respectively `-1` and `-24`)* so be sure to take this into account. Use

```
if int(windChill) in range(-24, 0):
#or
if int(windChill) in range(-1, -25, -1):
```

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `range` stops short of the second argument, so both of the above include a boundary error.

Answer (score 2):

**Your range function is backwards. But you do not need to include the last if condition if you use the if - elif- else syntax.**

**You should be using an if - elif- else statement here like below:**

```
print("Hello User What Is The Wind Chill Today?")
windChill = int(input())

if windChill <= -25:
    print("No School!!!")

elif windChill >= 0:
    print("Theres School ):")

else:
    print("Maybe school")
```

Comment: That's not the issue at all. All of the `if` conditions will be evaluated. The fact is, their last condition is an empty range unless they create a step of -1.

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` command is backwards, it should go from the smallest (most negative) number to the largest. If you want a range from -1 to -24, you should do `range(-24, -1)`

Comment: Also not true, it's perfectly fine for `range` to decrement, though it _is_ more understandable if it increments

Comment: @roganjosh `range` *can* decrement, but it won't by default. Without passing in a negative step, `range(x, y)` will not yield anything if `y <= x`

Comment: @CraigMeier which is precisely what I said on my first comment under the question.